# difference between linear separable hyperplane and affine separable hyperplane

Tags: optimization

What is the differece between linear separable hyperplane and affine separable hyperplane?

How does one represent a hyperplane graphically in R^2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, affine = linear plus a translation. Any line in the plane is an affine hyperplane. If it passes through the origin, it is also a linear hyperplane.